# Google people API ageRange min and max

Tags: google-api, google-plus, google-people-api

I needed to retrieve users age for analytics thus I tried using  `https://people.googleapis.com/v1/people/me?fields=ageRange&key={YOUR_API_KEY}`
but this only returns the following for any user older than 21.

```
{
  "ageRange": "TWENTY_ONE_OR_OLDER"
}
```

I was hoping to retrieve min and max range. Am I doing something wrong? OR should I just request birthday permissions and calculate the age myself.

Comment: nothing the age range is 21 - 21+.  Birthday is only going to work if the user has their birthday set to public.  Yes even if its the currently authenticated user.

Answer (score 0):

The age range is meant for apps to restrict users based on their ages for 18+ or 21+ usage. It only has certain predefined values: https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people#AgeRange

Birthday is your best option for getting the age of the user. Requesting the `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.birthday.read` permission should give you access to private birthdays too.